# Redirect all wild card subdomains and subdomain urls to the root domain and root domain urls using htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect my subdmain in this manner: `anysubdomain.my_domain.com` and its URLs must be redirected to root domain and its URLs respectively.

For example (1) if a user tries `http://anysubdomain.my_domain.com` it should redirect to`https://www.my_domain.com`.

And (2) if a user tries `http://anysubdomain.my_domain.com/anyurl` it should be redirected to `https://www.my_domain.com/anyurl`.

I was able to achieve (1) using below htaccess code:

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.my_domain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my_domain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
    </IfModule>
```

yet I could not do the (2) part. I'm sure we can do this with a modification for above htaccess code, but I don't know how.

I already have wildcard cname, that is why (1) perfectly working.

Also it is a WordPress site, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put these rules first :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.my_domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my_domain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

like this :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?my_domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my_domain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** clear browser cache the test.

Comment: you are a magician! I was literally googling and wasting my 5/6 hours ! it works.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this .htaccess to handle all subdomains:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)(my_domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Make sure to test it from new browser to clear browser cache fully.

Comment: unfortunately its not working. i mean .. i have used incognito mode as  well .. cleared cache fully from beginning. not working for (1) or (2) none of them :(

Comment: anything im missing here ?